# TWIG if/else to filter through templates

Tags: views, theming, forms

I am trying to write a TWIG else/if statement that loops through four different templates based on the number of customers are chosen from a list. So if a designer chooses 1 customer a certain template is used to create that view, and if they choose 3 customers a different template is used.

```
{% if content.field_featured_customers|length == 1 %}
{% include "node--customer--featured-full.hmtl.twig" with content.field_featured_customers %}
{% elseif content.field_featured_customers|length == 2 %}
{% include "node--customer--featured-split.html.twig" with content.field_featured_customers %}
{% elseif content.field_featured_customers|length == 3 %}
{% include "node--customer--featured-3block.html.twig" with content.field_featured_customers %}
{% else %}
{% include "node--customer--featured-carousel.html.twig" with content.field_featured_customers %}
{% endif %}
```

This is what I have tried so far, but nothing is rendered. I have created templates for all of the different views I am trying to display. Here is an example for the featured-full.html.twig

```
<div class="row">
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4">
{{ content.field_logo }}
</div>
<div class="small-12 medium-8">
<h3>{{ content.field_comapny_name }}</h3>
<p>{{ content.field_description }}</p>
<a class="button" href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong in the if/else statement, do I need to create different views, or is there something in the theme that I need to include?

Comment: You don't need of 'with' keyword. `include` itself pass the active context to new template, 'with' keyword is just if you want to add some template defined var to new template or declare which var will be passed to template with 'only' keyword. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not rendered at all, for sure, Twig not found your template file.

There is a var that store the base dir of your theme, just use it to define where is your template file.

**Twig file:**

```
{% include "#{directory}/templates/node/node--customer--featured-full.hmtl.twig" %}
```

Comment: while this didn't completely solve my problem, it did get me a lot closer - the file path allowed my template to render, but I had to include a preprocess function to render the field content

Comment: hmm, strange, I have similar situation in one of my templates (used in views instead node), and preprocess function wasn't needed at all. Again if you set any var in one template, you must use 'with' keyword in your include statement, if context itself is enough 'with' keyword is not required.